# Core Data table view exception crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, crash

this is a stack trace from Flurry crash analytics. Any Idea what is going wrong in my Core Data table view implementation?

```
Full Stack Trace:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x182d5c2d8 <redacted> + 132
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x194a280e4 _objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                      0x182d5c218 -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0
3   CoreData                            0x182a1fbc8 -[_PFBatchFaultingArray objectAtIndex:] + 204
4   Appname                             0x1000615e0 -[MasterViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:] + 124
5   Appname                             0x1000613b8 -[MasterViewController controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:] + 580
6   CoreData                            0x182b22d60 <redacted> + 4124
7   CoreData                            0x182aa1218 <redacted> + 200
8   CoreData                            0x182aa10e4 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 256
9   CoreData                            0x182a2c650 -[NSFetchedResultsController _managedObjectContextDidChange:] + 124
10  CoreFoundation                      0x182d022c4 <redacted> + 20
11  CoreFoundation                      0x182c3f450 __CFXNotificationPost + 2060
12  Foundation                          0x183b6ea80 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 72
13  CoreData                            0x182a2c5ac -[NSManagedObjectContext _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:] + 88
14  CoreData                            0x182a2c52c -[NSManagedObjectContext _createAndPostChangeNotification:withDeletions:withUpdates:withRefreshes:] + 364
15  CoreData                            0x182a2a9d4 -[NSManagedObjectContext _processRecentChanges:] + 2552
16  CoreData                            0x182a22dc4 <redacted> + 384
17  CoreFoundation                      0x182d142a4 <redacted> + 32
18  CoreFoundation                      0x182d11230 <redacted> + 360
19  CoreFoundation                      0x182d11610 <redacted> + 836
20  CoreFoundation                      0x182c3d2d4 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
21  GraphicsServices                    0x18c6936fc _GSEventRunModal + 168
22  UIKit                               0x18783af40 _UIApplicationMain + 1488
23  Appname                              0x1000d8d0c -[MainRowType .cxx_destruct] + 180
24  libdyld.dylib                       0x1950d2a08 <redacted> + 4
```

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting some exception and you are using that exception to init with coder.

The object which contains info is nil and calling init with coder. so it will be good to check **nil** before proceeding object.

We can't say more without code ;)

Comment: Thanks for help! I am not really good in stack trace reading... Can you tell what is nil? The index or the userinfo?

Comment: @Kreuzberg
I can't say more without code, but it seems your object (userinfo) is nil.